# Copying specific values from one list to another, type conversion

Tags: python, numpy, type-conversion

I have a list `x` with values:

```
[0.09086322  -0.66400483  -0.85750224, ... 73.92927078, 5.18024081, -17.12200886]
```

Here, I want to copy values in the range (-50, 50) from list `x` to another list `y`.

I have tried implementing the following code, but it doesn't seem to work

```
y = []
for i in x:
    if x[i] >= -50 and x[i] <=50:
    y.append(x[i])
```

I get the following error:

```
only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), numpy.newaxis (`None`) and
integer or boolean arrays are valid indices
```

Comment: You say `list`, but the error suggests that you are using a numpy array. If that's the case, and you want a numpy array as a result, you could do `y = x[(x >= -50) & (x <= 50)]`. This is one of the reasons why its important to post a _working_ script that shows the error. It answers questions about how the error was really generated.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
x = [0.09086322,-0.66400483,-0.85750224,73.92927078,55.18024081,-17.12200886]
y = []
for i in range(len(x)):
    if x[i]>= -50.0 and x[i] <=50.0:
        y.append(x[i])
print(y)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `i` instead of `x[i]` if you want to iterate on the list indexes, use `for i in range(x):`

Answer (score 0):

You are directly using the float values from your x list as indices, but x[0.09086322] is an invalid list access. You should directly use the values.

You can use a list comprehension rather than a for loop, it is easier to understand in my opinion :

```
>>> x = [-50.1, -50.2, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 50.1, 50.2]
>>> y = [v for v in x if v >= -50 and v <= 50]
>>> y
[0.1, 0.2, 0.3]
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to write `x[i]` as you have defined `x` (the structure you want to loop through) in the for loop already. Try:

```
y = []
for i in x:
    if i >= -50 and i <=50:
        y.append(i)
```

Answer (score 0):

When you run `for i in x:`, i is each element in the list rather than the index. You can check this by running the below:

```
for i in x:
    print(i)
```

Output:

```
0.09086322
-0.66400483
-0.85750224
73.92927078
5.18024081
-17.12200886
```

So when calling `x[i]` you are trying to call `x[0.09086322]`, which isn't possible. There are 2 ways to fix this code, the first is to replace `x[i]` with just `i`:

```
y = []
for i in x:
    if i >= -50 and i <=50:
        y.append(i)
```

Or loop through the indexes of x like below:

```
y = []
for i in range(len(x)):
    if x[i] >= -50 and x[i] <=50:
    y.append(x[i])
```